# input parameters of ant miner algorithm

Tags: algorithm

i have a datbase of EEG signal in which all signals were sampled at 256 samples and most files contain 23 EEG signals (23 derivations). For each EEG signal i extract 9 features that i will use it for the Ant Colony Classifier ,i use AntMiner+ algorithm for discovery of classification rule of my data but i can't decide which are the attribute and the attribute-values .
As i understand the attributes are the 23 derivations and the attribute-values are the 9 features that i extracted for each derivation .Am i right ?

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with the Java build tool that is Apache ant, right? So I removed that tag.

Comment: yes i didn't mean the Java build tool but i mean the Ant Miner Algorithm